# Unable to find element by xpath using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium4

I'm very new to Python and I'm trying to follow along with a video on web scraping with Selenium. In the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UOsRrxMKJYk), the person walking through how to do this has a whole bunch of different possible methods of finding an element on a web page. He is trying to identify a button on the page using an xpath.
[image]

However, when I am trying to do this, I have only two options (as seen below). Attempting to just use the same code to find the element by it's xpath simply doesn't work. I get an error that says

AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath'

What am I doing wrong here? Do I need to do something to be able to access these?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have downloaded the Selenium recently (I mean, not a year ago or so), the you are using the latest version of Selenium (Selenium 4), and there is a change in Selenium 4 where you use a `By` class to get to the locator strategy.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.find_element(By.ID, "element path")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "element path")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element path")
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "element path")
```

etc.

Same goes for `find_elements`

```
driver.find_elements(By.ID, "element path")
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "element path")
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element path")
driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "element path")
```

The key here is to import the `By` class and use it.

`find_element_by_xpath` and
`find_elements_by_xpath` etc are deprecated in Selenium 4.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest Selenium versions `driver.find_element_by_xpath` method was changed by `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,`.
So, instead of the old syntax like

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Username']")
```

Now you should use the new syntax like

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='Username']")
```

The same about all the other old `find_element_by_*` and `find_elements_by_*` methods.

Answer (score 0):

If I have lots lots of selenium cases in which

```
find_element_by_xpath()
```

is  used, it would be a pain to have each line updated to

```
find_element(By.XPATH, ...)
```

Is there some kind of wrapper to python wrapper to handle it ?